# How to use variables outside of .observe

Tags: swift, dictionary, firebase

I currently have the code below. This successfully pulls the information from firebase and then appends it to the array of dictionaries. My question is how do I use this dictionary outside of .observe? I understand the issue of async vs sync with firebase, but I haven't found a good explanation on how I can use this data in another function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("vendors").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let spot = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
        for each in spot{
            let name2 = each.value["name"] as! String
            let booth2 = each.value["boothNum"] as! String
            let desc2 = each.value["description"] as! String

            self.name = name2
            self.booth = booth2
            self.desc = desc2

            let dict1: [String: String] = ["name" : name2, "booth" : booth2, "desc" : desc2]

            self.vendorDict.append(dict1)

            dump(self.vendorDict)

        }
    })
```

this successfully dumps the info I need in the .observe but if I dump the dictionary outside it says it is empty.

Comment: Do you know *why* you cannot access your "spot" var? It's called *variable scope*. It's declared inside a closure, so you won't be able to access it. If you define it with a different scope - say outside of *viewDidLoad()* - you'll be able to access it. (You probably will need to add *self* in front if it inside the closure, but that's okay.)

Comment: Im trying to access an array of dictionaries which is outside of my viewDidLoad(). By appending the spot info to the array I should still be able to access the array, no?

Comment: I think I know the issue. Can you post your definition of *vendorDict*?

Comment: var vendorDict = [[String: String]]() This is how I created vendorDict. This is created in the overall class to be used in any function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to call needed function at the end of the closure, but outside of the 'for' loop. This way you will have the dictionary populated, and still be on the same thread. 
Other options are - adding a completion block and creating a protocol (can't elaborate more on these two since not comfortable with them myself).